# i3 window manager configuration. on Arch linux

Tags: i3

i am trying to setup i3 window manager on my arch linux . what is  ****bindsym and mod**** ? 
before setting this up and i wanted understand what is all these and and what these will do. 
Some one please help me to understand .
btw i am beginner in linux

Comment: Everything you need to know is either in the i3 man page or documented on the i3 website. Take a look here: https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#configuring

Comment: I will say that if you are a brand-new beginner to Linux, I recommend that you not start with Arch. Ubuntu is a great first step into the Linux world, and you can still run i3 perfectly well. As Peschke said, reading through the official documentation is the way to go.